# How come div block is moved down when there is enough space?

Tags: html, css

I have a rather simple problem. For some reason, `div.actionBar` is moved down even when there should be enough space in the parent `div`:

```css
.venueInfoSection {
 position: relative;
        width: 960px;
}

.venueInfoSection .topVenueSection {
 line-height: 0;
 padding: 20px;
}

.venueInfoSection .topVenueSection .mainIconWrapper {
 display: inline-block;
 line-height: 0;
 margin-right: 20px;
 max-width: 88px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.venueInfoSection .topVenueSection .primaryInfo {
 display: inline-block;
 line-height: 20px;
 vertical-align: top;
 width: 512px;
}

.venueInfoSection .actionBar {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 58px 0 0 15px;
 text-align: right;
 vertical-align: top;
 width: 285px;
}
```

```html
<div class="venueInfoSection">
    <div class="topVenueSection">
        <div class="mainIconWrapper"><img src="images/surfspot_88.png" height="88" width="88">
        </div>
        <div class="primaryInfo">
            <div class="venueNameSection">
                <h1 class="venueName" itemprop="name">Title</h1> </div>
            <div class="categories"> <span class="unlinkedCategory">Surf Spot</span> </div>
            <div class="locationInfo"> <span class="venueCity">38 Bourke St</span> </div>
            <div class="bottomVenueSection"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="actionBar"> <span class="saveAction actionBtn"> <div class="saveButton saveToListAction inactive" title="Save to my saved places!"> <span class="saveAction actionBtn"><span class="buttonLeft"><img src="images/button_icon_saveribbon-9c5999c2ee53e7d96.png" height="16" width="16"></span><span class="buttonRight unsaved"><span class="label">Save</span></span>
            </span>
        </div>
        </span><span class="shareAction actionBtn"> <div class="doubleShareButton" title="Share this place with friends!"> <span class="shareAction actionBtn"><span class="buttonLeft"><img src="images/button_icon_saveribbon-9c5999c4703e7d96.png" height="16" width="16"></span><span class="buttonRight"><span class="label">Share</span></span>
        </span>
    </div>
    </span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

If the widths are subtracted:

- `venueInfoSection` is 960px wide
- `topVenueSection` has 20px padding
- `mainIconWrapper` is 88px wide + 20px margin
- `primaryInfo` is 512px wide
- `actionBar` is 285px wide + 15px margin

So 960-20-20-88-20-512-285-15=0

How come `actionBar` is moved down even when there should be enough space? It seems to be inlined with the other two blocks only if the width is set to 277px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set display to `inline-block` certain whitespace in your HTML becomes rendered as spacing between each element.  That whitespace is what is causing your layout to break.

The easiest alternative would be to replace every instance of `display: inline-block` with `float: left` though there are innumerable alternatives (ex: See 'Fighting the Space Between Inline Block Elements' https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/ )

```css
.venueInfoSection {
 position: relative;
        width: 960px;
}

.venueInfoSection .topVenueSection {
 line-height: 0;
 padding: 20px;
}

.venueInfoSection .topVenueSection .mainIconWrapper {
 float: left;
 line-height: 0;
 margin-right: 20px;
 max-width: 88px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.venueInfoSection .topVenueSection .primaryInfo {
 float: left;
 line-height: 20px;
 vertical-align: top;
 width: 512px;
}

.venueInfoSection .actionBar {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 58px 0 0 15px;
 text-align: right;
 vertical-align: top;
 width: 285px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="venueInfoSection">
    <div class="topVenueSection">
        <div class="mainIconWrapper"><img src="images/surfspot_88.png" height="88" width="88">
        </div>
        <div class="primaryInfo">
            <div class="venueNameSection">
                <h1 class="venueName" itemprop="name">Title</h1> </div>
            <div class="categories"> <span class="unlinkedCategory">Surf Spot</span> </div>
            <div class="locationInfo"> <span class="venueCity">38 Bourke St</span> </div>
            <div class="bottomVenueSection"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="actionBar"> <span class="saveAction actionBtn"> <div class="saveButton saveToListAction inactive" title="Save to my saved places!"> <span class="saveAction actionBtn"><span class="buttonLeft"><img src="images/button_icon_saveribbon-9c5999c2ee53e7d96.png" height="16" width="16"></span><span class="buttonRight unsaved"><span class="label">Save</span></span>
            </span>
        </div>
        </span><span class="shareAction actionBtn"> <div class="doubleShareButton" title="Share this place with friends!"> <span class="shareAction actionBtn"><span class="buttonLeft"><img src="images/button_icon_saveribbon-9c5999c4703e7d96.png" height="16" width="16"></span><span class="buttonRight"><span class="label">Share</span></span>
        </span>
    </div>
    </span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

You could also utilize a Flex grid depending on the level of browser support you need to accommodate.

Answer (score 1):

It is whitespace that is messing with your layout. `line-height:0` does not suffice.

Try setting the font-size to zero:

`div {font-size:0;}
h1,span{font-size:initial;}`

Consider using a flex-layout instead.

```css
div {font-size:0;}
h1,span{font-size:initial;}
.venueInfoSection {
 position: relative;
        width: 960px;
}

.venueInfoSection .topVenueSection {
 line-height: 0;
 padding: 20px;
}

.venueInfoSection .topVenueSection .mainIconWrapper {
 display: inline-block;
 line-height: 0;
 margin-right: 20px;
 max-width: 88px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.venueInfoSection .topVenueSection .primaryInfo {
 display: inline-block;
 line-height: 20px;
 vertical-align: top;
 width: 512px;
}

.venueInfoSection .actionBar {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 58px 0 0 15px;
 text-align: right;
 vertical-align: top;
 width: 285px;
}
```

```html
<div class="venueInfoSection">
    <div class="topVenueSection">
        <div class="mainIconWrapper"><img src="images/surfspot_88.png" height="88" width="88">
        </div>
        <div class="primaryInfo">
            <div class="venueNameSection">
                <h1 class="venueName" itemprop="name">Title</h1> </div>
            <div class="categories"> <span class="unlinkedCategory">Surf Spot</span> </div>
            <div class="locationInfo"> <span class="venueCity">38 Bourke St</span> </div>
            <div class="bottomVenueSection"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="actionBar"> <span class="saveAction actionBtn"> <div class="saveButton saveToListAction inactive" title="Save to my saved places!"> <span class="saveAction actionBtn"><span class="buttonLeft"><img src="images/button_icon_saveribbon-9c5999c2ee53e7d96.png" height="16" width="16"></span><span class="buttonRight unsaved"><span class="label">Save</span></span>
            </span>
        </div>
        </span><span class="shareAction actionBtn"> <div class="doubleShareButton" title="Share this place with friends!"> <span class="shareAction actionBtn"><span class="buttonLeft"><img src="images/button_icon_saveribbon-9c5999c4703e7d96.png" height="16" width="16"></span><span class="buttonRight"><span class="label">Share</span></span>
        </span>
    </div>
    </span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```